# Convert panda dataframe into json object with groupby

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Basically I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
       num    platform  region
id          
569094  10  AMZN    in
569094  5   AMZN    ca
569094  12  NFLX    us
385687  15  DIS in
385687  20  NFLX    ca
```

I need to convert this into json however its not as straight forward as creating a json records, since I need to use groupby

This is what I did so far

```
 main_df = main_df.groupby('id').agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
    result = main_df.to_json(orient='index')
    parsed = json.loads(result)
    print(parsed)
```

which gives me this

```
{
   "385687":{
      "num":[
         15,
         20
      ],
      "platform":[
         "DIS",
         "NFLX"
      ],
      "region":[
         "in",
         "ca"
      ]
   },
   "569094":{
      "num":[
         10,
         5,
         12  
      ],
      "platform":[
         "AMZN",
         "AMZN",
         "NFLX"
      ],
      "region":[
         "in",
         "ca",
         "us"
      ]
   }
}
```

**Expected output**

```
"id":385687,
  "platforms":{
     "DIS":{
        "in":15      
     },
     "NFLX":{        
        "ca":20
     }

  "id":569094,
  "platforms":{
     "AMZN":{
        "in":10
        "ca":5
      
     },
     "NFLX":{        
        "us":12
     }
```

any help would be appreciated, I can't find anyone asking similar question

Comment: There is a problem in your expected output because in a JSON file you can't repeat the same key in one object, so for example, in the second ID you can't have the "AMZN" key twice, it will be preserved just one. So, you need to change the structure of the expected output, maybe try that the content of "platforms" be an array that contains objects.

Comment: @jjsantoso you are correct, its a mistake from my end. Should be"platforms":{
     "AMZN":{
        "in":10, "ca":5

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but there's no question here, and it's not clear what exactly you need help with, especially since your expected output is invalid (in multiple ways). Please read [ask]. See also [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). You can [edit] if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Its a little bit complex, but this should work:

```py
df = pd.read_clipboard() # copy data from OS question

def make_json(x):
    data = {
            "id": x.index.min(),
            "platforms": {pl: {} for pl in x["platform"].unique()}
           }
    for pl, reg, num in zip(x["platform"], x["region"], x["num"]):
        data["platforms"][pl].update({reg: num})
    return data

df.groupby('id').apply(make_json).tolist()
```

```
[{'id': 385687, 'platforms': {'DIS': {'in': 15}, 'NFLX': {'ca': 20}}},
 {'id': 569094,
  'platforms': {'AMZN': {'in': 10, 'ca': 5}, 'NFLX': {'us': 12}}}]
```

Comment: wow, thank you man. That seems to do the trick

Comment: Be a good contributor and if any of the solutions works for you, mark it as the answer and consider upvoting the ones that worked.

Answer (score 0):

A pure pandas approach:

```
out = (df
   # form the region dictionaries
   .groupby(['id', 'platform'])
   .apply(lambda d: d.set_index('region')['num'].to_dict())
   .groupby('id')
   # aggregate by platform
   .agg(lambda d: d.droplevel('id').to_dict())
   .reset_index(name='platforms').to_dict('records')
 )
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 385687,
  'platforms': {'DIS': {'in': 15},
                'NFLX': {'ca': 20}}},
 {'id': 569094,
  'platforms': {'AMZN': {'in': 10, 'ca': 5},
                'NFLX': {'us': 12}}},
]
```